# How to use websockets with Ionic?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, websocket

I am developing an Ionic application with websockets and I have two problems.

First on my avd (android 5) I have had an app with working websockets and after playing with

```
preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"
preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19"
```

or maybe with cordova websocket plugins? Can't pin point exactly but only this seems relevant. The websocket won't open.

Second the websocket object was not defined on my android phone (4.1.2) so what are best practices for Ionnic to use websockets with android?

I currently removed some cordova websocket plugins that I checked if they would fix websockets for my phone. I don't have much to go on now there is no documentation that I have found usefull and websocket doesnt give an error just won't open. Regular rest service works and fetches data from server.

The server-side works ok scince web client does not have such problems.

Comment: I am probably done with programming for today, but will update on my progress tomorrow:)

Comment: First breakthrough. When removing one cordowa websocket plugin ir removes <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> line from android manifest I needed to add it. Now I suspect that my rest service could not work also but results were cached